# Buttons and Pie Css

Tags: css, css3pie

I have a weird issue with CSS Pie and iE8 where Pie correctly applies the border-radius property to an element but the background of the element (a gradient or a flat color) overflows the borders and looks like it is at the top, hiding the actual element.

I have been working with Pie CSS for a while. I do know that while using it on a PHP environment the pie.php is needed and that the correct location for Pie is at the root of the site. I never had this problem but now that Im using a responsive framework Im having this issue. The button us made with this structure:

```
<p class="btn">
  <a href="#">Learn More</a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {

    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 36px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 36px !important;
    border: 1px solid #a0c401;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff,
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.31); /* Remove this line if you dont want a dropshadow on your buttons*/
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff,
                0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.31); /* Remove this line if you dont want a dropshadow on your buttons*/
    background: #c0eb03; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c0eb03 0%, #a8cd01 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c0eb03), color-stop(100%,#a8cd01)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c0eb03 0%,#a8cd01 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c0eb03 0%,#a8cd01 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c0eb03 0%,#a8cd01 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #c0eb03 0%,#a8cd01 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c0eb03', endColorstr='#a8cd01',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(top, #c0eb03 0%,#a8cd01 100%);
    behavior: url("PIE.php");
    z-index: 10 !important;
}
.btn a, .btn:hover a {
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(199, 243, 6, 1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'AvantGardeGothicITCW01D 731075';
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6a8100;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(199, 243, 6, 1);
}
```

Comment: What does the CSS look like?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Kevin I just added the CSS to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the filter that's overflowing; it's not needed if you're letting PIE render the gradient via -pie-background. Remove the filter and all should be well.